# MyPy error paths in PyCharm Terminal not clickable

Tags: pycharm, mypy

when I run MyPy in the Terminal of PyCharm in the root directory of the project, the paths of the result are blue, underlined, and clickable.
[image]

But when I run mypy from the subfolder (mono repo with front and backend) where the actual python code lives, it is not clickable. This is also the folder with my pyproject.toml lives.
[image]

Is there a way to get this clickable? Maybe by setting a working directory for the terminal somewhere? I didn't find anything like that. I have my code root directory marked as sources root, but couldn't figure out how to get paths clickable.

Comment: Presumably the paths are interpreted as relative to the project directory (and thus point to nowhere), whereas they are actually relative to the directory from which mypy is called.

Comment: Yep, my thinking. That's why I thought setting a working directory for the terminal might be nice. Or maybe there is a way to change the mypy output

Comment: This is a byproduct of pycharms automatic link generation.  Without changing the paths, there isn't anything you can do natively to pycharm to make the links work.  There is, however, a plugin that (mostly) does what you're looking for called 'Awesome Console', but it has some issues and hasn't been maintained.  YMMV

Comment: "*maybe there is a way to change the mypy output*": How about running it from the parent directory?

Comment: @InSync I tried, but then I would need to move my MyPy config to the parent directory. But that does not make sense. Especially since I keep all config in the pyproject.toml. Breaking project structure for this doesn't sound appealing to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a CLI option to output absolute paths: [`--show-absolute-path`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-show-absolute-path).

Here's the result on my machine (I'm using Windows/PowerShell, but that shouldn't make a difference):

[image]

Comment: Thant's it. Thank you! I use it as show_absolute_path in the config file though.